# java - Release a Maven project as library with several artifacts

Tags: java, maven

This might be trivial but i'm having issue on how to do it. Currently i have a Maven project that generates a jar file (with other dependent jars), 3 scripts and 3 property files. It can be run standalone without problem.

Now i would like to release the artifacts from this project into our in house Maven Repository, so that others can use this project artifact and do customization. The question is, since there are non jar files in the build artifact, how should i release them?

Currently i'm using `maven-jar-plugin` to create the jar file, and `maven-resources-plugin` to copy the resource file to the target folder.

Any idea or correction is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

To be clear, what i intend to do is to allow other developer to reuse the classes of this project while adding custom features and settings.

Currently the output of the project are:

```
engine.jar
run.sh
runDaemon.sh
loadJob.sh
mapping.xml
```

For others, they can reuse engine.jar, while adding a jar of their own and edit the mapping.xml to suit their need.

**EDIT2**

Decided to export a single jar from the library project, and use Archetype to generate a template project instead. Accepting the answer below as it provides clear information for packaging several artifacts together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to pack those configs into a zip file. You should look at the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) which is created exacly for those cases (releasing one or more non jar artifacts).

There is [an example with some text files](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html) which is similar to your case.

Comment: Why are you using a link from the archives instead of the up-to-date sites: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html

Comment: Thanks Martin for the pointer. However this let me ponder how should i set up the project that want to use this release. Example if my project is distributed as a zip file, then the project that use it need to download the zip, extract it, and re-setup the whole project again with the additional jar? Is there a maven plugin for doing the "de-assembly" part?

Comment: Depends what you do with it. A common case I know is deploying config files, and this is usualy done using a job (Jenkins or other). If the objective is to use those files inside another Java project, why not bundle them directly with the jar then?

Comment: Edited the question to give a clearer picture on what i need to achieve. I can't bundle them with the jar as others will need to change them. On second thought, should i just release the jar file for usage?